# Optical Mark Reader SR-410 program to read examination card in vb6

Tags: excel

I am developing a program for marking multiple choice answer sheets. For example:

[image]

I'm trying to convert the output of data from the OMR device into a human readable format, e.g. Q1 - 1, Q2 - 2, etc for the example sheet.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Screen.MousePointer = 11

MSComm1.Handshaking = comRTS

MSComm1.RTSEnable = True
MSComm1.CommPort = 1
MSComm1.Settings = "19200,E,7,2"
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
MSComm1.InBufferCount = 0
MSComm1.OutBufferCount = 0
Screen.MousePointer = 0
End Sub



Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim Response As String
Dim TMCount As String
Dim CMode As String
Dim EMode() As String
Dim ReciveCnt As Integer

If MSComm1.DSRHolding = False Then
MsgBox "The device is not turned on" + Chr(&HD) + _
"or no communication cable is connected. !!", 16, "SR-430 Sample Program-1"
Screen.MousePointer = 0
Exit Sub
End If
If MSComm1.CTSHolding = False Then
MsgBox "The device is not in the receivable state. !!", 16, "SR-430 Sample Program-1"
Screen.MousePointer = 0
Exit Sub
End If

MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H18) + Chr(&HD)
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until MSComm1.InBufferCount = 1
Response = MSComm1.Input
If Response <> Chr(&H6) Then
MsgBox "Initialization fails !!"
Screen.MousePointer = 0
Exit Sub
End If
MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H13) + "12" + Chr(&HD)
MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H10) + "T" + Chr(&HD)
MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H2) + "2" + Chr(&HD)

MSComm1.Output = "?" + Chr(&HD)
ReciveCnt = 1
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until MSComm1.InBufferCount = ReciveCnt
Response = MSComm1.Input
If Response <> "0" Then

MsgBox "Error occurs!!" + Chr(&HD) + _
"Read status = " + Response
Screen.MousePointer = 0
Exit Sub
End If

MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H5) + "T" + Chr(&HD)
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until MSComm1.InBufferCount = 3
TMCount = MSComm1.Input
Text1.Text = "Timing mark count : " + TMCount + Chr(&HD) + Chr(&HA)

MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H10) + "C001" + TMCount + Chr(&HD)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until MSComm1.InBufferCount = 3 * Val(TMCount)

CMode = MSComm1.Input
Text1.Text = Text1.Text + "C Mode : " + CMode + Chr(&HD) + Chr(&HA)
ReDim EMode(Val(TMCount)) As String
Dim DataLength As Integer
Text1.Text = Text1.Text + "E Mode : " + Chr(&HD) + Chr(&HA)
MSComm1.Output = Chr(&H10) + "E001" + TMCount + Chr(&HD)
ReciveCnt = 0

Response = " "
Do
DoEvents
Response = Response + MSComm1.Input
DataLength = InStr(Response, Chr(&HD))
If DataLength <> 0 Then
EMode(ReciveCnt) = Left(Response, DataLength)
Text1.Text = Text1.Text + Format(ReciveCnt + 1, "000") + "-Column:" + EMode(ReciveCnt) + Chr(&HA)
Response = Mid(Response, DataLength + 1)
ReciveCnt = ReciveCnt + 1
End If
Loop Until ReciveCnt = Val(TMCount)
Screen.MousePointer = 0


End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
MSComm1.PortOpen = False
End
End Sub
```

which gives the result below for the example sheet

```
Timing mark count : 036
C Mode : 00800500500500500500500500A005011300A8124201402800D1F000000000000000000F1F00000001F000F0006003F000000F000000
E Mode : 
001-Column: 8
002-Column:9;
003-Column:9;
004-Column:9;
005-Column:9;
006-Column:9;
007-Column:9;
008-Column:9;
009-Column:8:
010-Column:9;
011-Column:7;
012-Column:23
013-Column:024;
014-Column:25:
015-Column:79
016-Column:68
017-Column:89;
018-Column:34567
019-Column: 
020-Column: 
021-Column: 
022-Column: 
023-Column: 
024-Column:89:;
025-Column:34567
026-Column: 
027-Column: 
028-Column:34567
029-Column:89:;
030-Column: 
031-Column:12
032-Column:234567
033-Column: 
034-Column:89:;
035-Column: 
036-Column:
```

How can I modify the code to give the desired output in terms of question / answer

Comment: Could you post your code exactly what the errors are?

Comment: i have already edit the post by adding my code